# Using a Setter on an Event

Tags: wpf, events, user-interface

I'm using `Setter`'s on my WPF-UI elements to define the layout.

For example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
</Style>
```

I'd also like to use them to give them all the same Event handler, such as:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="GotFocus" Value="TextBox_GotFocus" />
</Style>
```

But it seems I cannot use Setter on Events, only on Properties.

Is there a way to give all my TextBoxes the same `GotFocus` event handler using something similar to a `Setter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<EventSetter>` instead.

.
.

Comment: Thank you!  I overlooked that, but its exactly what I need.